# About Amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have such problem:
I have [Droplr](http://droplr.com)-like Adobe AIR application, which uploads files to remote location and returns short links for those files. I want to upload all these files to Amazon S3. But, as it is Adobe AIR application and everyone can see its source(and S3 API keys), I cant upload files directly to Amazon S3. As I understood, if someone will get API keys from application's source, he will be able to upload files to my S3 account and I will pay for that.
I wanted to solve this by uploading files from application to my server and PHP script will upload them to Amazon S3. Like a proxy. But it will be double traffic and slow operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is that you can use signed URLs.  Your application can request an upload URL from your server.  Your server then generates a signed URL to send back to the application which is then used to upload the file.  You can also set the expiration time on signed upload URLs.

Comment: The problem is I have Adobe AIR application and everyone can see its sources. So they can copy the URL where server returns signed URLs and use it.

Comment: You don't put your keys in the application.  Your application makes a call to your server (which has the keys) and the server responds with a signed upload url for the application to use for file uploading.

Comment: It's done on the fly and you set the URL to expire after a time you specify. (maybe 10 minutes to upload a file?)  You don't store the URL in the app.  For example:

Comment: -App - "I need to upload this file"
-App -> server "Send me an upload url for this file"
-Server -> App "http://some.S3.url.com/?signed&with&expiry
-App uses URL to upload file

(man, the formatting in these comments doesn't allow for line breaks, that sucks :-)

Comment: Yes, I understood. For example this is a URL where application receives signed URLs: http://example.com/get_signed_url/USER_ID/

Comment: And everyone can copy this URL and receive signed URLs! Am I correct?

Comment: Ah yes, that could be a problem.  I assumed you had a way to validate that requests were coming from your app.  You'd need to have that ability.  

Even using the method of posting to your server and having it upload to S3 could be abused if you don't verify that the requests are coming from your app.

Answer (score 1):

This [blog article](http://shlomoswidler.com/2009/08/how-to-keep-your-aws-credentials-on-ec2.html) talks about keeping AWS credentials secret. Whilst it covers EC2 mostly, there's some stuff in there about S3 too.

Comment: http://transloadit.com/ - How this works? I think it uploads files first to their server and then to S3.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is the Token Vending Machine, an application you can run to allow mobile and other client apps to obtain temporary credentials without revealing or embedding your account credentials in your application. You can read more about the TVM approach here:

http://aws.amazon.com/articles/4611615499399490